# Downloading all netbeans dependencies at once

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, dependencies, repository

When I first deploy\run or create a new java ee project (maven, ejb, ...), netbeans downloads a lot of files into repository. When I disconnect internet connection, I discover again that I cannot perform some actions because some new dependencies are required.

Since I'm not always connected to interent, I need to find some link so that I can download ALL **JAVA EE** dependencies, testing my apps offline on GlassFish or whatever local server.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It's not a really good idea to try to download all EE dependencies. You end up with a big mess.
If you want to work offline you can download your dependencies first and than use -o flag of mvn command to build your project offline.

You can also set up your own Maven repository. You can use Artifactory to manage your dependencies easily.